# Are US cops trained to escalate the violence?

Tags: united-states, weapons, law-enforcement

While in many countries the policemen are trained to de-escalate or are even legally bound to do so, US cops kill suspects so often, because allegedly  escalation is part of their training. Allegedly the escalation of violence is being taught as a method of *"establishing the authority"*.

While there are [some sources confirming](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/06/28/us/long-taught-to-use-force-police-warily-learn-to-de-escalate.html) that de-escalation is not something emphasized in their training, are there sources confirming that they're actually trained to *escalate*?

Comment: "allegedly escalation is part of their training" Who is alleging this?

Comment: I've seen it numerous time in comments to articles covering shootings, I vaguely remember similar claims in articles covering Ferguson.

Comment: I voted to close because I am not sure whether the claims mean "Officers are explicitly trained to try to escalate every situation", or "Officers training fails to teach them to de-escalate, which means, in practice, they make situations worse", or "Officers are trained to escalate (only) along the [use of force continuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_of_force_continuum), so they don't jump straight to relying on lethal weapons in every situation.", or something else.

Comment: @Oddthinking: Or a third alternative, which is that they're trained to de-escalate, but often aquire an attitude which leads them not to make use of that training.

Comment: @jamesqf: That may the truth in practice, but it is not consistent with the question, so that surely isn't the claim.

Comment: Keep in mind that "US police" is not a homogeneous group. Most police forces are local to their municipality, and the type and quality of training found in each place is likely to vary greatly.

Comment: Here's another article: http://www.theatlantic.com/national/archive/2014/12/police-gun-shooting-training-ferguson/383681/